# Nuget Package issue

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

```
  <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
```

I have tried automatic restore, I have also added these packages manually but nothing happens. I am using visual studio 2019, on MACOS Big Sur

Comment: Did you use click the `Manage NuGet Packages` from `Project` menu, or you edited the `packages.config` file?

Comment: Yes, the missing file is present but the error is still the same.

Comment: Did you change `package.config` file or manage NuGet packages from the GUI?